# how to insert multi records in oracle table using pandas data frame

Tags: python

I have an input txt file of 6 lines ,I want to insert them in a oracle DB table every record start from ''INS'' ,example: 
first three lines are considered as  one record with 3 fields values `(INS*Y*18*030 , REF*0F*1234567,REF*0T*0234567),` 
and last 3 lines are considered as one record with 3 fields values
`(INS*Y*17*030,REF*0K*6234567,REF*0J*4234567)`.
the below code is working for one record insertion and not for 2 records  to insert, any idea to fix this code to insert for multi records ? thanks you.

Here is the python code :

```
lol = list()
with open ("text.txt", 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if line[0:3]  in  ["INS","REF"]:
         lol.append(line.strip())         
    dfs1 = pd.DataFrame(lol)
    by_column = [dfs1[x].values.tolist() for x in dfs1.columns]
        for row in by_column:
          cursor.execute("""
         insert into table (a,b,c)
         values (:1,:2,:3) """, row)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: try with executemany

Comment: It's not worked because it's iterated over two records and put them in one data frame .thanks